# Enrolling Android 5.1 device fails without reason

Tags: android-management-api

I am trying to enroll a fleet of Android 5.1 devices which did never receive a newer version of Android and are not working with any third party ROM. So we're stuck on 5.1.

As the Google Play Services in the ROM was so old, that I couldn't even install the Android Device Policy DPC, I updated the Play Services in the ROM using an update.zip, wiped the device and then enrolled the device using a NFC tag.

Unfortunately, enrollment is not working, and I'm not even getting an error message. The DPC seems to set itself as the device owner, but no enrollment is taking place - the device does not show up on the API, and upon launching the DPC from the application drawer and clicking on the "Get started"-button, we always are presented with "Your system cannot be managed by this app. Please contact your administrator".

Well, I am the administrator and I have no clue, why this is failing.

Has anyone an idea, what the DPC is looking for before deciding that the device cannot be managed? Or how to get a more meaningful message out of the DPC?

Answer (score 1):

The Android Management API doesn't support NFC provisioning on Android 5.1. It is only supported on Android 6.0 and above.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#provisioning_methods) previously mentioned that 5.1 is supported, that was an error and we have now updated it.

Comment: So how do you enroll a COSU 5.1 Android device then? If I understand correctly, there is no way to enroll a 5.1 device to be a COSU device?

Comment: That's correct. Fully managed mode (and therefore COSU) is only supported on 6.0+. Work profile however is supported on 5.1+.